# How to get else option that prints out ("This is not a number"). Strings and Ints HELP! (ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:)

Tags: python-3.x, string, if-statement, int, state

***ERROR MESSAGE:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:"***

> Thanks

```
# Name
name = input("Enter Name: ")
# Age
age = int(input("Enter Age: "))

if age == str():
    print("Not a Number!")
else:
    pass


# Age - 100 equals
subage = 100 - age

# Take the result of previous expression and add to year.
age100 = subage + 2020

# Print out results

print(name,"! " "You will be 100 years of age in the year of: ", age100)
```

*just writing more so i can get this thing to post.*
sdfsdff
**sfsdf**

Comment: Read about handling exceptions in Python using `try-catch` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put age = int(input("Enter Age: ")) inside of a try block and follow it with an except block for if an error occurs:

```
try:
    age = int(input("Enter Age: "))
    # Age - 100 equals
    subage = 100 - age

    # Take the result of previous expression and add to year.
    age100 = subage + 2020

    # Print out results

    print(name,"! " "You will be 100 years of age in the year of: ", age100)
except ValueError:
    print(“This is not a number”)
```

Comment: Hey thanks !!! :) I tried it and it worked. Really Helpful Matt!

Comment: No problem.  Could you please upvote the answer since it helped?